# Do tensorflow code, wrapped in using custom estimator api use gpu efficiently in google cloud-ml engine or in local machine?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, tensorflow-estimator

I am training a neural network in google cloud ml-engine . I built the network using tensorflow high level apis like `tf.layers`, `tf.losses`, `tf.dataset`. The code is also wrapped in using the custom estimator api. The job is running for long time. The network is so huge that it should use large amount of gpu, but in the jobs details page of ml-engine it's showing, it is not using master cpu as well as the gpu. Although some amount of memory in master cpu and gpu is getting used. I have used, "complex_model_s" as master cpu, "standard-gpu" as a worker, and a parameter server of type "standard". It is not outputting any newer log or checkpoints also since it has started training. Why the ml-engine is not using the gpu , and not outputting any new log and checkpoint files?
If I use local machine with NVIDIA gpu for the training will it use gpu? Or any change is needed in the code?

Answer (score 1):

The distribution strategy currently supported by estimator's train_and_evaluate is best for sparse models. Sounds like you have a very deep model.

So, to maximize training speed, try using a single machine (ie no workers). To minimize cost, use the smallest machine that fits the size of your network.

If you are willing to experiment, try using a worker with multiple devices and add in a mirrored distribution strategy (it's still very early prototype though)

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/distribute

The best option, if your use case supports it, for maximum speed and minimum cost is to use TPUs.